# Angularfire: Create a $FirebaseObject from a child of a $FirebaseObject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm building a timeline system which is fundamentally constructed from lots of different directives.

In an abstraction, each project looks like this:

```
<project id='id'>
  <h3 ng-bind='project.name'></h3>
  <timeline items='project.timelines[0]'>
    <timeline-item item='item' ng-repeat='item in timeline'>
      <comments items='item.comments'>
        <comment item='comment' ng-repeat='comment in comments'>
          <user id='comment.user'></user> 
          <p ng-bind='comment.body'></p>
        </comment>
      </comments>
    </timeline-item>
  </timeline>
</project>
```

At the top level, I create the object for the project by getting hold of a raw firebase reference to the project, then wrapping it in the `$firebase` wrapper. Finally, I grab a copy ready for the model using `$asObject()`.

This techniques words fine for the `<project>` directive, because I have access to all of the top level properties as well as the `.$save()` method.

However, when I pass a child of this object down to a child directive, I lose the ability to call `.$save()`. This means the model updates perfectly within the view, but doesn't save within Firebase.

In general terms, **how can I extract a `$FirebaseObject` or `$FirebaseArray` to pass to a directive, from an existing `$FirebaseObject`**?

I know I can get hold of the original reference to achieve this, but in practice this looks something like:

```
...
// timeline-item.js
scope: {
  item: '='
},
link: function(scope) {
  scope.item; // is a $FirebaseObject
  scope.comments scope.item.$ref().child('comments');
},
template:
"<comments items='comments'></comments>"

// comments.js
scope: {
  items: '='
},
link: function(scope) {
  scope.items; // is a Firebase reference
  scope.items = $firebase(scope.items).$asArray();
}
```

Maybe this problem can be solved with `$bindTo`? But I can't figure out how that would work across multiple directives either.

Comment: You can get the `$ref` back from the `$firebase` object and construct the correct new `$firebase` object based on that. But it would be easier to help if you *show* your controller/service code, instead of describing it.

Comment: There are many different types of timeline item and the service code that goes together to describe the full timeline system is a lot more complex that I could justify putting in a SO question, when the goal was this abstract in nature.

I'm aware that I can get the $ref back, but then you have to rebuild your path with a call to `.child()` and then pass that child reference down, only to have to re-wrap it with `$firebase` and fetch the new object. That feels messy. In previous versions of AngularFire, I would have done this with `$child` calls, but the 0.8x API has removed it.

Comment: If you can't [simplify your code to a simple problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then a simple answer won't be possible either. $child was removed because it's superfluous and in all cases that people were utilizing it, they utilized it incorrectly to hack features into their objects or manipulate data. We've provided new tools for these in the form of $extend. Your data structure is overly complex. [Avoid building nests](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-denormalizing-data) when possible.

Comment: For another argument as to why you should simplify this to a definable problem set, see [the XY problem](http://goo.gl/PWKCLQ), which you've fallen into here. And note that we specifically addressed nested structures like this in [paragraph 2 of the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html): "[AngularFire] is also not ideal for synchronizing deeply nested collections inside of collections. But deeply nested collections should typically be avoided in distributed systems."

Comment: Hang on, I know there's a lot of detail here but I think the emboldened text "__how can I extract a $FirebaseObject or $FirebaseArray to pass to a directive, from an existing $FirebaseObject?__" is both simple and well defined as a problem? The fact that you have recommended the guide on flattening data proves that I have not fallen into the XY, as you've been able to understand the problem well enough to suggest a solution. However, that is a useful guide, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`$asArray` has a function called `$getRecord` that I think would solve this for you.

```
var list = $firebase(ref).$asArray();
var rec = list.$getRecord("foo"); 
rec.update(data);
```

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-getrecordkey

Comment: The `$getRecord` method doesn't return a FirebaseObject. It just returns a plain old Javascript one.